# Plotly.js - gd.data must be an array

Tags: javascript, html, plotly

I am using the Plotly.js library to draw 3D graphs. My plan is to draw 4 traces into one 3D graph. But I encounter some strange behavior of my website when I try do this.

Sometimes, when I load my site I get no error and all 4 traces are loaded perfectly in my 3D graph. But at another time not all of my traces are loaded into my graph and I get the error:

```
Error: gd.data must be an array.
```

This is my function for adding the traces from a CSV file:

```
function addTraceFromCSVdarkColor(divname,link)
{
    Plotly.d3.csv(link, function(err, rows)
    {
        function unpack1(rows, key) 
        {
            return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
        }        

        var trace1 = {
            x: unpack1(rows, 'x'),
            y: unpack1(rows, 'y'),
            z: unpack1(rows, 'z'),
            mode: 'lines',
            type: 'scatter3d',
            opacity: 0.5,
            line: 
            {
                color: 'rgb(252, 185, 0)',
                size: 2,
                opacity: 0.5
            }
        };

        var data = [trace1];
        Plotly.addTraces(divname,data);
    });
}
```

And this is how i create the 3D graph:

```
function print3DMultiGraphMain(divname,link)
{
    Plotly.d3.csv(link, function(err, rows)
    {
        function unpack1(rows, key) 
        {
        return rows.map(function(row) { return row[key]; });
        }        

        var trace1 = {
            x: unpack1(rows, 'x'),
            y: unpack1(rows, 'y'),
            z: unpack1(rows, 'z'),
            mode: 'lines',
            type: 'scatter3d',
            line: 
            {
                color: 'rgb(252, 185, 0)',
                size: 2
            }
        };

        var data = [trace1];
        var layout = {
            autorange: false,
            width: 800,
            height: 800,
            scene: 
            {
                aspectratio: 
                {
                    x: 1,
                    y: 1,
                    z: 1
                },
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                camera: 
                {
                    center: 
                    {
                        z: 0
                    },
                    eye: 
                    {
                        x: 1.25,
                        y: 1.25,
                        z: 1.25
                    },
                    up: 
                    {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        z: 1
                    }
                },
                xaxis: 
                {
                    type: 'linear',
                    range: [0, 200],
                    zeroline: false
                },
                yaxis: 
                {
                    type: 'linear',
                    zeroline: false,
                    range: [0, 200]
                },
                zaxis: 
                {
                    type: 'linear',
                    zeroline: false,
                    range: [0, 200]
                }
            },
        };
        Plotly.newPlot(divname, data, layout,{displayModeBar: false});
    });
}
```

And this is how I call the functions in my html file:

```
<script>
print3DMultiGraphMain('tester','out1.csv');

addTraceFromCSVlightColor('tester','out2.csv');
addTraceFromCSVdarkColor('tester','out3.csv');
addTraceFromCSVlightColor('tester','out4.csv');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error `gd.data must be an array` is going to occur when the div containing the chart does not have a property `data`of type Array.
This might be because the chart is not properly initialized yet when you try to add traces, e.g. in case your asynchronous `MultigraphMain` call completes after one of your `addTrace` calls.

In order to circumvent the problem you have to wait for the chart to be created before you try to add traces. `Plotly.newPlot()` returns a promise. I have attached a minimal showcase below.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter'
};

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function getInitialData() {
  // simulate HTTP call
  await sleep(2000);
  return trace1;
}

getInitialData().then((trace) => {
 Plotly.newPlot('myPlot', [trace]).then(
    () => {
     Plotly.addTraces('myPlot', [trace2]);
    }
  );  
})

// if you call addTraces here, it is going to fail
// Plotly.addTraces('myPlot', [trace2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plotly.js/1.49.5/plotly.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPlot">
</div>
```