# Plotly js gd.data must be an array

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

So I am getting the error gd.data must be an array when I am attempting to add a trace to an existing graph with addTraces. The plotly is within an ajax call. I have tried explicitly declaring an array and adding the new trace data to it, and I have tried ensuring that the x and y coordinates are an array in same way. I am still getting the error gd.data must be an array. 
I saw that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846210/plotly-js-gd-data-must-be-an-array) was asked earlier, but did not have any answers. I was wondering if there was any solution to this issue, or if there was another way that I could add traces to an existing graph.

```
//adding the traces
let dd = [];
let pd = [];
dd.push(dateData);
pd.push(pricingData);
Plotly.addTraces('graphing-area', [{
    x: dd,
    y: pd,
    name: ticker,
    type: 'scatter',
    showlegend: true,
}]);
```

```
let trace = [{
    x: [dateData],
    y: [pricingData],
    name: ticker,
    type: 'scatter',
    showlegend: true
}];
let layout = {
    padding: {b:0},
    title: {
        text:'Bid Price vs Maturity',
        font: {
            family: 'Courier New, monospace',
            size: 18
        },
    }
};
Plotly.newPlot('graphing-area', trace, layout, {displayModeBar: false});
```

Does anybody have a solution or a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: This error is going to occur when the chart you are trying to add traces to does not have a data array yet, i.e. you first called `Plotly.newPlot(graphDiv, null, layout)` before adding the trace.